# adding textview and button in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, expandablelistview

how could we add TextView and button in Expandable List View.
Like explained 
Root is Branch name
           first leaf is Address
           second leaf is Email
           third leaf is phone number.
           fourth leaf some details

I get branches and it gets loaded into ExpandableListView.
Expandable Listview should have many TextViews like Name, address, email and telephone number.
Next to Textview   of Email and Phone number there would be buttons. So as to make calls or to mail them.(next to every leaf there will be a button)
Please let me know any tutorial or examples on how to have many TextViews inside Expandable List View. I am getting ListViews data from database.
The Editable ListView grows dynamically.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your own custom expandable list..

Have a look at this link:

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/12/expandable-list-and-checkboxes.html

It should help you through..